# keyPressed() event carries on firing even after i stop pressing the key

Tags: java, processing

So the object that I've drawn starts moving either up or down depending on what arrow key I've pressed but once i let go it carries on moving in the same direction not stopping unless i press a random key. If i press up it starts moving up and carries on moving up even after letting go of up. If i then press down it starts moving down and carries on moving down even after i am no longer pressing it. If any key other than up arrow key or down arrow key is pressed whilst it is moving it stops moving.

MAIN SKETCH:

```
Defender defender1;
PImage background;
int x=0; //global variable background location

void setup() {
    size(800,400);
    background = loadImage("spaceBackground.jpg");
    background.resize(width,height);
    defender1 = new Defender(200,200);
}

void draw () {
    image(background, x, 0); //draw background twice adjacent
    image(background, x+background.width, 0);
    x -=4;
    if(x == -background.width)
        x=0; //wrap background
    defender1.render();
    defender1.keyPressed();
}
```

Defender Class:

```
class Defender {
    int x;
    int y;

    Defender(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void render() {
        fill(255,0,0);
        rect(x,y,50,20);
        triangle(x+50,y,x+50,y+20,x+60,y+10);
        fill(0,0,100);
        rect(x,y-10,20,10);
    }

    void keyPressed() {
        if (key == CODED) {
            if (keyCode == UP) {
                defender1.y = y-1;
            } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
                defender1.y = y+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your `defender1.keyPressed()` function every time `draw()` is called.

The `key` and `keyCode` variables hold the most recently pressed key, regardless of whether that key is currently being held down.

To check whether any key is currently being pressed, you could use the `keyPressed` variable.

Or you could change your code to only call `defender1.keyPressed()` from the sketch-level `keyPressed()` function.

You can find more info in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input) is a tutorial on user input in Processing.

Comment: Thank you so much man i used keyPressed to check if the key is being held down and it worked and thanks for the shameless self promotion as well i will probably use it quite a lot as it seems pretty easy to understand.